# How to compare date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here I need to compare date using SQL Server 2008. I want show details of the table if the specific date appears more than one time.

Example:

```
create table datetest
(
  columnx nvarchar(10),
  columny nvarchar(10),
  coldate date,
  coltime datetime
)

insert into datetest values('a123','b123','2014-01-01','01:05:00.000');
insert into datetest values('a123','b456','2014-01-01','02:15:00.000');
insert into datetest values('a123','b789','2014-01-01','03:25:00.000');
insert into datetest values('a321','b321','2014-02-03','10:05:00.000');
insert into datetest values('a243','b243','2014-03-04','11:05:00.000');
insert into datetest values('a243','b243','2014-03-04','12:05:00.000');
insert into datetest values('a243','b243','2014-03-04','12:05:00.000');
```

Now I need to show only that records whose dates are greater than one appear in the table.

Expected result:

```
columnx    columny   coldate         coltime 
-------------------------------------------------------
a123        b123    2014-01-01  1900-01-01 01:05:00.000
a123        b456    2014-01-01  1900-01-01 02:15:00.000
a123        b789    2014-01-01  1900-01-01 03:25:00.000
a243        b243    2014-03-04  1900-01-01 11:05:00.000
a243        b243    2014-03-04  1900-01-01 12:05:00.000
a243        b243    2014-03-04  1900-01-01 12:05:00.000
```

My attempt:

```
select * 
from datetest 
where coldate = '2014-01-01' or coldate = '2014-03-04';
```

**Note**: But this is not the right way for the large records to check.

Comment: Can u make ur question clear?

Comment: SQL server supports regular [comparison operators such as `<`, `>`, `=` and `BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) for dates. What's not working?

Comment: "Q:  I need to show only that records whose dates are greater than one appear in the table."  You want to list all dates in the table that are greater than any of the dates in the table???  What exactly are you trying to query for?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: For multiple dates you can also try 
select * from datetest where coldate in ('2014-01-01','2014-03-04');

Comment: @FoggyDay, If the date `2014-01-01' appears twice in the column then I need to show it with all details.

Comment: Ah!  Then please upvote and accept Satihish's answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

```
select * from datetest
where coldate in (select coldate from 
datetest group by coldate having count(*) > 1)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b78a/3)